# Boto3 / Python - Listing recently modified objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pagination, boto3

I'm looking to list objects but I am only really interested in the last 1,000 that have been modified that same day.

I have seen that Boto3 supports pagination and getting specific objects by key name + a modified date. However, I can't see any mechanism that allows listing objects by their modified date?

[Boto3 S3 Object.get()](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.get) - This supports returning a key if its modified on a certain day.

[Boto3 Paginators](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Paginator.ListObjects) - This allows listing listing a certain number of objects, but doesn't allow you to determine the listing method.

I can achieve this by first listing all objects, then iterating over that list of objects, but this incurs the full costs, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I'm trying to do this to prevent having to list an entire bucket (which has more overhead costs).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no base functionality that offers this capability.

An alternative is to activate [Amazon S3 Inventory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html):

> Amazon S3 inventory is one of the tools Amazon S3 provides to help manage your storage. You can simplify and speed up business workflows and big data jobs using the Amazon S3 inventory, which **provides a scheduled alternative to the Amazon S3 synchronous List API operation**. Amazon S3 inventory provides a comma-separated values (CSV) flat-file output of your objects and their corresponding metadata on a daily or weekly basis for an S3 bucket or a shared prefix (that is, objects that have names that begin with a common string).

Comment: Hey, this definitely works for 24 hour / weekly requirements, but we actually need an active mechanism for polling. We've actually decided to try a different approach using SQS. I think the answer to this is basically "No it can't be done". Thanks for your help.